# MongoDB GeoJSON weird query results

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, coordinates, geojson

I am using GeoJSON to store coordinates of locations that i want later on to query by proximity,

my schema looks like the following:

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var BranchSchema = new Schema({
parentId: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: 'The ID of the restaurant is required.',
    index: true
},
name: {
    type: 'String',
    required: 'The name is required.'
},
loc: {
    'type': {
        type: 'String',
        default: 'Point'
    },
    coordinates: {
        type: [Number],
        default: [0,0]
    }
}
});
BranchSchema.index({loc: "2dsphere"});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Branch', BranchSchema);
```

I am using mongoose and my query looks something like the following:

```
Branch.where('loc').near({
    center: [long, lat],
    maxDistance: proximity,
    spherical: true
}).exec(function (err, branches) {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(400)
            .send({
                message: errors.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
    }
    return res.json(branches);
});
```

i added a new branch to the database with the following coordinates Latitude:34.237918
Longitude:36.002197
and i query the database with the following coordinates:
Latitude:33.882957
Longitude:35.502319
and a maxDistance of 100

the difference between these 2 coordinates is more than 100m however the database return results, what am i missing???

Answer (score 0):

Can you double check that you're doing the query that you think you are doing? Your query works fine for me:

```
> db.test.drop()
> var p = { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [36.002197, 34.237918] }
> var q = { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [35.502319, 33.882957] }
> db.test.insert({ "loc" : p })
> db.test.ensureIndex({ "loc" : "2dsphere" })
> db.test.count({
    "loc" : {
        "$near" : {
            "$geometry" : q,
            "$maxDistance" : 100
        }
    }
})
0
```

Comment: Hey @wdberkeley, thanks a lot for the reply, your code works just fine however I am not being able to get the same results with Mongoose, any idea or hints?